# Android app cannot connect to localhost over 4G

Tags: android, apache, websocket, localhost

I have Apache server running in localhost and, while my android app is on the same WiFi network and has my computers ip address to locate the server, the app can connect and send messages. However, if I switch from WiFi within the app to 4G, I can no longer connect to the server and send messaages.

The server address within the app:

```
Global ipAddress = new Global();
    private final String AUTHENTICATION_SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://"
            + ipAddress.getIpAddress() + ":4430/BackendDatabase/";

public String sendHttpRequest(String params) {
        URL url;
        String result = new String();
        try {
            url = new URL(AUTHENTICATION_SERVER_ADDRESS);
            HttpURLConnection connection;
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
      ...etc
```

How should the server be configured differently so as to allow the phone to send and receive messages while not in the local network?

Answer (score 0):

you can't connect to your localhost using 4G because they aren't in the same network. you should
 use wifi instead. and when using wifi, you should use you computer's IP not `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` you have to use e.g `192.168.1.2` (you computer's IP) and if you are using emulator, you should use `10.0.2.2` as ip address to connect.

Comment: What I was asking is now that my app works, I want to move to the phones 4G instead of just wifi. How can I configure the server to allow for that?

Comment: please accept my answer if it was helpful.

for that, you should have static ip address for your server and you can't access your computer without static ip over 4G.

Comment: So should I setup a server not in local host but hosted by Amazon out another?

Comment: exactly that's what you have to do

Comment: ok, if you wish to change your answer and outline the steps I can mark it correct